# Cannot to connect to Google API Client, GooglePlayServices

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to use Google Play Services, especially Games API, and  I stuck at this.

I've already configured and compiled two samples from Google and run on my device. Both of them works well, achievements, leaderboards that I've configured from my side on Google Console.

So I want to go further, make my own app with GPServices from scratch. Using the latest stable Android Studio 2.3.3 with the latest SDKs

[image: SDKs]

I created a new project, the configured as Google Guides and samples show us.

**Android Manifest:**

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "playservices.workshop.akbolatss.gplayservices"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.4"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

And **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Games.API)
                .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onConnectionFailed " + connectionResult.getResolution() + " " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("TAG", "onConnectionFailed");
    }
}
```

The **PROBLEM** is that it fails in 100% times. And logs never tell what goes wrong. I dunno where I'm missing, it looks like a waste of time. If you have time, please, check the project, mby it specifically doesn't work on my machine

Link to Project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6wsqlvnhno60g8/GPlayServices.rar?dl=0

Link to Samples: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Comment: Have you configured the project in google developer console, provided the SHA-1 key for auth2.0 and finally have you added the app id from developer console to your ids.xml or strings.xml file?

Comment: Yes, I did these steps. Still nothing happens when I call googleApi.connect()  method

Comment: Having you also added your email in the testing accounts in developer conaole?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got your specific key in order to access the API?

Comment: Nope, I didn't, Inside manifest I've declared it 

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                android:value="@string/app_id" />